# Python 'dict' object not callable?

Tags: python, flask

I am using Flask on python 2.7 and I want to return a value as a json value, I'm trying to do it as this,

```
    user_id = 100
    return_id = {}
    return_id['user'] = user_id

    return return_id
```

However I'm getting the following error,

Here is the full traceback,

> 127.0.0.1 - - [03/Oct/2016 15:04:16] "POST /add_new_patient HTTP/1.1" 500 -
>   127.0.0.1 - - [03/Oct/2016 15:04:30] "OPTIONS /add_new_patient HTTP/1.1" 200 - [2016-10-03 15:04:30,199] ERROR in app: Exception on
>   /add_new_patient [POST] Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/mnt/663E60F33E60BE25/Users/acer/Documents/code/thalback/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
>   line 1988, in wsgi_app
>       response = self.full_dispatch_request()   File "/mnt/663E60F33E60BE25/Users/acer/Documents/code/thalback/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
>   line 1642, in full_dispatch_request
>       response = self.make_response(rv)   File "/mnt/663E60F33E60BE25/Users/acer/Documents/code/thalback/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
>   line 1746, in make_response
>       rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)   File "/mnt/663E60F33E60BE25/Users/acer/Documents/code/thalback/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py",
>   line 847, in force_type
>       response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))   File "/mnt/663E60F33E60BE25/Users/acer/Documents/code/thalback/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py",
>   line 871, in run_wsgi_app
>       app_rv = app(environ, start_response) TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code. Can you add some more details to your question please?

Comment: I tried your code, it works perfectly. Is there any other place in your code where you call the dictionary ?

Comment: do json.dumps() if it's an ajax call.

Comment: You are attempting to call a dictionary, eg `some_dict()`, but it's impossible to be more specific without seeing the code that's causing this error, preferably a [mcve]. And you should also post the full error message, starting with the `traceback` line.

Comment: @PM2Ring added the full error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it's ok to return a string from a Flask handler with `json.dumps`, the preferred way is to use [`jsonify`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.json.jsonify), which adds the correct `Content-Type` and accepts a variety of arguments, e.g. you can just call:

```
return jsonify(user=100)
```

Comment: Hi when I try to run the correct code it's not returning any output, ```return jsonify(user=user_id)1``` it doesn't return anything. However ```return jsonify(user='text')``` returns the value

Comment: @rksh I presume that the trailing `1` in your commend is a typo?

Comment: sorry yes typo, fixed and working thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

> I am using Flask on python 2.7 and I want to return a value as a json value

**You are not returning a JSON string**!

You are returning a python object. When Flask *sees* a python object, it tries to call it. When you return a dictionary, it assumes it is a callable and tries to call it.

What you need to do is:

```
import json

def your_function(..):
    ...
    return json.dumps(return_id)
```

PS: As correctly pointed out by @bereal in his answer, the above approach wont add `Content-Type: application/json` header in the response. You'd want to use `jsonify(..)` as shown in his answer.